# Prevent sending AJAX request with the dev Console?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I created a memory game using javascript, html, css and PHP without using a framework, i use php to save the player name and the score into MySql database am getting those variables from my javascript and send them using **jQuery Ajax post request** this is how my code is looks like:

```
$("#submitScore").on("click", function() {
  let playerName = $('#playerName').val();
  
  if(isEmptyOrSpaces(playerName)){
    playerName = "Unknown";    
  }
  
  let data = {"player_name": playerName, "score": totalScore};
  $.post("./backend/save_score.php", data, function(){
    fetchHighScores();
    $("#submitScore").prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

everything works fine the only problem that i have is that anyone can send **an ajax request** using the dev console, so if someone put this line in console and hit enter

```
$.post("./backend/save_score.php", {"player_name": "Cheater", "score": 1111111111});
```

it will be saved into my database, am sure that theres a solution for that i searched for CSRF attacks but i didnt got proper answer **am new in Ajax world** , **How can i prevent this kind of actions?** i dont want to use a framework am keeping my game as Simple as possible? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

What you need to do instead is change your approach, and add some server-side validation. Let the JavaScript send your server the user's answers to the questions, rather than the final score. That way the server can check if the answer is correct or not, and the server will calculate the score and return it. This will stop anyone from sending their own made-up score.

Comment: thanks for ur respons, so u mean that i should send a request whenever the player get **correct pair of cards** and count them using my php and then calculate the score?

Comment: Yes. Or you could send all the answers in one request at the end. It's up to you.

Comment: Actually, it's still not quite right. Don't send the fact that the cards are correct or not - that still allows for cheating. Just send the server which cards the user chose. The server must decide whether they are correct or not.

Comment: but wouldn't be possible that someone can send manipulated data with same approach ?

Comment: They can send you pairs of cards to test, yes. If there are other rules you need to enforce, you'll need to think of how the server might validate those, such as maintaining its own copy of the game state and checking whether the submitted move is valid in the current scenario, things like that. Basically you can't trust _anything_ the client sends you. Always double-check it.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot prevent sending AJAX requests from Dev Console, but you can make it more difficult. For example, you can add a captcha to your page which, if integrated properly, makes it extremely difficult to send the form using a bot.

However, you will need to define what a suspect request looks like, what patterns are suspect and validate the request against them.

Comment: I would appreciate to know what needs to be improved in this answer.